# Creating an Image marker of a rounded white on black arrow in Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have been working on an AR app in Vuforia and have stumbled upon a problem. I'd like to use the following image for tracking (since it's what the device I'd use it on has), but the rating is quite bad (only 2 stars), even though it is a perfect white on black image (perfect contrast). What could I do to make the image a better tracking target, if anything can be done at all?

[image: marker]

Thanks for any ideas!

Features found by Vuforia:
[image: marker with features]

Comment: Well the images look like the edges are blended eg it’s not 2 colours but got a bunch of grey round the edges. Perhaps a more binary image would help

Comment: it's exported directly from Illustrator where the colors are only white and black, I tried with both a jpeg and a png, so not sure why the blend happens. What could I do to make it more binary?

Comment: Id say bmp? But im not a graphics expert but I often import pictures for crafting reasons and a lot of pictures are compressed or blended in some way. BMP is a bit more raw.

Comment: BMP isn't supported by Vuforia, only JPEG or PNG...

Comment: You would need a find a way to reduce the compression then

Comment: I'll see what I can do, though not sure if it's possible since it compresses automatically once I upload to the developer portal

Comment: Sometimes depending on the software there are options to change compression

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sticking to the best practices for designing Image Targets: https://library.vuforia.com/objects/best-practices-designing-and-developing-image-based-targets

In the article it's discussed how circles are not great graphics to be able to be tracked. Also I'd argue that this could become a problem because of the repetitiveness of the graphic.

Comment: I would love to follow the guide if there was a chance, however, the project I'm working on already has buttons that look like that and cannot be changed. I'm starting to wonder if the tracking is at all possible with a layout like that, since the targets are also fairly small...